# Square bracket for single & multiple LineItems in xml to json

Tags: json, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping, xslt-3.0

How to get square bracket or Array for single or multiple 'Details' lineitems.
Need to get the square bracket or Array [ even for single line 'Details' too. we have more than 1 line 'Details'.
The requirement is to populate the [ even from single line 'Details'.

xmlFile for single Line 'Details':

```
<root>
    <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
    <LastName>Fin</LastName>
    <Details>
        <Id_Number>111</Id_Number>
        <Location>NC</Location>
        <Contact>
             <PhoneNumber>+1 323</PhoneNumber>
         </Contact>
    </Details>
</root>
```

ExpectedJsonFile:

```
     {
    "FirstName": "Alex",
    "LastName": "Fin",
    "Details": [
      {
        "Id_Number": 111,
        "Location": "NC",
        "Contact": {
          "PhoneNumber": "+1 323"
        }
      }
    ]
 }
```

xml File with multiple Line 'Details:

```
<root>
        <FirstName>Alex</FirstName>
        <LastName>Fin</LastName>
        <Details>
            <Id_Number>111</Id_Number>
            <Location>NC</Location>
            <Contact>
                 <PhoneNumber>+1 323</PhoneNumber>
             </Contact>
        </Details>
        <Details>
            <Id_Number>222</Id_Number>
            <Location>TX</Location>
            <Contact>
                 <PhoneNumber>+1 323</PhoneNumber>
             </Contact>
        </Details>
        <Address>
            <Locality>Urban</Locality>
            <Distance>
               <Miles>2</Miles>
            </Distance>
            <Commute>Yes</Commute>
         </Address>
         <Address>
            <Locality>Rular</Locality>
            <Distance>
               <Miles>1</Miles>
            </Distance>
            <Commute>Yes</Commute>
         </Address>
    </root>
```

Expected Jsonfile for multiple LineItems'Details'

```
    {
    "FirstName": "Alex",
    "LastName": "Fin",
    "Details": [
      {
        "Id_Number": 111,
        "Location": "NC",
        "Contact": {
          "PhoneNumber": "+1 323"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id_Number": 222,
        "Location": "TX",
        "Contact": {
          "PhoneNumber": "+1 323"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Address": [
      [
          {
        "Locality": "Urban",
        "Distance": {
          "Miles": 2
        },
        "Commute": "Yes"
      }
      ],
      [
          {
        "Locality": "Rular",
        "Distance": {
          "Miles": 1
        },
        "Commute": "Yes"
      }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

xsltCode:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="json-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
    <string key="{local-name()}">{.}</string>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[(*) and . castable as xs:double]">
    <number key="{local-name()}">{.}</number>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="*[*]">
    <xsl:param name="key" as="xs:boolean" select="false()"/>
    <map>
      <xsl:if test="$key">
        <xsl:attribute name="key" select="local-name()"/>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or self::Details or self::Contact">
                  <array key="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="self::Address">
                        <array>
                          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                            <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                          </xsl:apply-templates>                        
                        </array>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                          <xsl:with-param name="key" select="false()"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                      </xsl:otherwise>                      
                    </xsl:choose>
                  </array>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()">
                    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="true()"/>
                  </xsl:apply-templates>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </map>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is generating an array when the group of like-named nodes contains two or more items:

```
<xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
    <array key="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
    </array>
</xsl:when>
```

so the simplest fix would be to use the same logic when the element name is "Details":

```
<xsl:when test="current-group()[2] or self::Details">
```

Or a better design might be to make it data-driven; have a global variable containing the list of element names for which you want to force array output, and test the element for membership in this list.

Comment: Thanks much Michael - How to get the Address Line item as arrays"Address": [
      [
       {
        "Locality": "Urban"
      }
      ],
      [
       {
        "Locality": "Rular"
      }
      ]
    ]

Comment: Please don't ask new questions as a supplementary to an existing questions. And when you ask questions, please explain what you've tried and where you're having difficulty, otherwise it just feels like you want someone else to do your job for you.

Comment: I tried the template but the child elements are not populating"Distance" in the json - 'Address section'. child elements are not recognizing. Any usggestions to get the child elements from 'Address'
        },<xsl:when test="self::Address">
                        <xsl:iterate select="current-group()">
                          <array>
                            <map>
                              <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            </map>
                          </array>
                        </xsl:iterate>
                      </xsl:when>

Comment: Thanks much for the support...I modified the code...its working for single or multiple lineitems & Child elements....</xsl:when> <xsl:when test="self::Address"> <xsl:iterate select="current-group()"> <array> <xsl:apply-templates select="self::Address"> </xsl:apply-templates> </array> </xsl:iterate> </xsl:when> –